# Josephus problem (counting out)

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

### The challenge

Write a function that takes two positive integers \$n\$ and \$k\$ as arguments and returns the number of the last person remaining out of \$n\$ after counting out each \$k\$-th person.

This is a code-golf challenge, so the shortest code wins.

### The problem

\$n\$ people (numbered from \$1\$ to \$n\$) are standing in a circle and each \$k\$-th is counted out until a single person is remaining (see the corresponding [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem)). Determine the number of this last person.

E.g. for \$k=3\$ two people will be skipped and the third will be counted out. I.e. for \$n=7\$ the numbers will be counted out in the order \$3 \, 6 \, 2 \, 7 \, 5 \, 1\$ (in detail \$\require{cancel}1 \, 2 \, \cancel{3} \, 4 \, 5 \, \cancel{6} \, 7 \, 1 \, \cancel{2} \, 4 \, 5 \, \cancel{7} \, 1 \, 4 \, \cancel{5} \, 1 \, 4 \, \cancel{1} \, 4\$) and thus the answer is \$4\$.

### Examples

```
J(7,1) = 7      // people are counted out in order 1 2 3 4 5 6 [7]
J(7,2) = 7      // people are counted out in order 2 4 6 1 5 3 [7]
J(7,3) = 4      // see above
J(7,11) = 1
J(77,8) = 1
J(123,12) = 21
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### GolfScript, 17 bytes

```
{{@+\)%}+\,*)}:f;
```

Takes `n k` on the stack, and leaves the result on the stack.

### Dissection

This uses the recurrence `g(n,k) = (g(n-1,k) + k) % n` with `g(1, k) = 0` (as described in the Wikipedia article) with the recursion replaced by a fold.

```
{          # Function declaration
           # Stack: n k
  {        # Stack: g(i-1,k) i-1 k
    @+\)%  # Stack: g(i,k)
  }+       # Add, giving stack: n {k block}
  \,*      # Fold {k block} over [0 1 ... n-1]
  )        # Increment to move from 0-based to 1-based indexing
}:f;
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation, please?

Comment: @Sherlock9, I managed to figure out what I was doing despite almost 3.5 years having passed. Who says that GolfScript is read-only? ;)

Comment: Ahem. s/read/write/

Comment: Sorry. I've only started learning Golfscript two or three days ago and I every time I read your code, I kept thinking I'd missed something. ... Ok, I'm still missing something, how does folding `{k block}` over `[0..n-1]` get you `g(0,k) 0 k` to start with? Sorry, if I'm posting these questions in the wrong place.

Comment: @Sherlock9, fold works pairwise, so the first thing it does is evaluate `0 1 block`. Very conveniently, that happens to be `g(1, k) (2-1) block`. So it's starting at `g(1,k) 1` rather than `g(0,k) 0`. Then after executing the block, it pushes the next item from the array (`2`) and executes the block again, etc.

Comment: OH! Ok that makes sense. Thanks @Peter Taylor

Answer (score 14):

### Minsky Register Machine (25 non-halt states)

Not technically a function, but it's in a computing paradigm which doesn't have functions per se...

This is a slight variation on the main test case of my first [MRM interpretation challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1864/simulate-a-minsky-register-machine-i):
[image: Josephus problem as Minsky register machine]

Input in registers `n` and `k`; output in register `r`; it is assumed that `r=i=t=0` on entry. The first two halt instructions are error cases.

Comment: I think you have to adjust your machine slightly. If I read it correctly the output is zero-indexed, isn't it?

Comment: I was thinking the other way: if `k=1` then `r=0`. Hmm, I have to think about this one again...

Comment: As I read your diagram, `i` is simply counting from `2` to `n` while `r` is the register which accumulates the result.

Comment: @Howard, I looked up the comments I made when I first wrote this and you're right. Whoops. Now corrected (I believe - will test more thoroughly later).

Answer (score 7):

### Python, 36

I also used the formula from wikipedia:

```
J=lambda n,k:n<2or(J(n-1,k)+k-1)%n+1
```

Examples:

```
>>> J(7,3)
4
>>> J(77,8)
1
>>> J(123,12)
21
```

Answer (score 6):

#### Mathematica, <s>38</s> 36 bytes

Same Wikipedia formula:

```
1~f~_=1
n_~f~k_:=Mod[f[n-1,k]+k,n,1]
```

Comment: `If[#<2,1,Mod[#0[#-1,#2]+#2,#,1]]&`

Answer (score 5):

### C, 40 chars

This is pretty much just the formula that the above-linked wikipedia article gives:

```
j(n,k){return n>1?(j(n-1,k)+k-1)%n+1:1;}
```

For variety, here's an implementation that actually runs the simulation (99 chars):

```
j(n,k,c,i,r){char o[999];memset(o,1,n);for(c=k,i=0;r;++i)(c-=o[i%=n])||(o[i]=!r--,c=k);
return i;}
```

Comment: Save a character: `j(n,k){return--n?(j(n,k)+k-1)%-~n+1:1;}`.

Answer (score 5):

### dc, 27 bytes

```
[d1-d1<glk+r%1+]dsg?1-skrxp
```

Uses the recurrence from the Wikipedia article. Explanation:

```
# comment shows what is on the stack and any other effect the instructions have
[   # n
d   # n, n
1-  # n-1, n
d   # n-1, n-1, n
1<g # g(n-1), n ; g is executed only if n > 1, conveniently g(1) = 1
lk+ # g(n-1)+(k-1), n; remember, k register holds k-1
r%  # g(n-1)+(k-1) mod n
1+  # (g(n-1)+(k-1) mod n)+1
]
dsg # code for g; code also stored in g
?   # read user input => k, n, code for g
1-  # k-1, n, code for g
sk  # n, code for g; k-1 stored in register k
r   # code for g, n
x   # g(n)
p   # prints g(n)
```

Answer (score 4):

### J, 45 characters

```
j=.[:{.@{:]([:}.]|.~<:@[|~#@])^:(<:@#)>:@i.@[
```

Runs the simulation.

Alternatively, using the formula (31 characters):

```
j=.1:`(1+[|1-~]+<:@[$:])@.(1<[)
```

I hope Howard doesn't mind that I've adjusted the input format slightly to suit a dyadic verb in J.

Usage:

```
   7 j 3
4
   123 j 12
21
```

Answer (score 4):

#### GolfScript, <s>32</s> 24 bytes

```
:k;0:^;(,{))^k+\%:^;}/^)
```

*Usage:*
Expects the two parameters *n* and *k* to be in the stack and leaves the output value.

(thanks to Peter Taylor for suggesting an iterative approach and many other tips)

The old (recursive) approach of 32 chars:

```
{1$1>{1$(1$^1$(+2$%)}1if@@;;}:^;
```

This is my first GolfScript, so please let me know your criticisms.

Comment: `1-` has special opcode `(`. Similarly `1+` is `)`. You don't have to use alphabetic characters for storage, so you could use e.g. `^` instead of `J` and not need a space after it. You have far more `$`s than are usual in a well-golfed program: consider whether you can reduce them using some combination of `\@.`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks a lot for these great tips! It's pretty hard to grasp all the Golfscript operators and I overlooked these two very straightforward one. Only by applying the first two suggestions I manage to shorten the code by 5 chars. I'll also try to remove the `$` references.

Comment: Also, recursion isn't really GolfScript's thing. Try flipping it round and doing a loop. I can get it down to 19 chars (albeit untested code) that way. Hint: unroll the function `g` from the Wikipedia article, and use `,` and `/`.

Comment: Actually, make that 21. I forgot to pop `k` at the end.

Comment: @Peter Taylor: Actually, you can build a 19 chars solution (not using *each* but *fold*).

Comment: @Howard, cunning. Nice one.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks, the iterative solution is much better than the recursive one in GS. I'm still thinking of ways to get this shorter.

Comment: `{,{\2$+\)%}*)\;}:f;` Make sure you understand *why* it works ;)

Comment: One final trick: rather than using 2 characters to access `k` inside the loop and then 2 more to discard it at the end, we can pull it inside using `+` to get down to 17 characters: `{{@+\)%}+\,*)}:f;` I doubt that can be improved.

Comment: @PeterTaylor These things are a work of art. I really liked the second example that adds the `3` and the code block together to make a code block that uses the `3`.

Comment: In the 19 chars I think there should be a `\\` at the beginning (it seems to expect the parameters in the opposite order).

Comment: One more thing: isn't is OK for the purpose of this site to leave out the function wrapper? For example, I think `{@+\)%}+\,*)` might be acceptable (the usage being that it expects two params in the stack and leaves the result at the end)

Comment: Yes. As I said: untested code. I've tested the 17-char one, though, because I thought it up on the way home from work. In general, when the question asks for a function, give a function; when it asks for a program, give a program; and when it doesn't specify, pick whatever's in your favour but state what you picked.

Comment: @PeterTaylor If you want to post your solution as answer I'd accept it as the currently shortest one.

Answer (score 3):

#### Groovy, 36 bytes

```
def j(n,k){n>1?(j(n-1,k)+k-1)%n+1:1}
```

Answer (score 3):

### R, 48

```
J=function(n,k)ifelse(n<2,1,(J(n-1,k)+k-1)%%n+1)
```

Running Version with examples: http://ideone.com/i7wae

Answer (score 2):

#### Scala, 53 bytes

```
def?(n:Int,k:Int):Int=if(n<2)1 else(?(n-1,k)+k-1)%n+1
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 68

```
j n=q$cycle[0..n]
q l@(i:h:_)k|h/=i=q(drop(k-1)$filter(/=i)l)k|1>0=i
```

Does the actual simulation. Demonstration:

> GHCi> j 7 1
>   7
>   GHCi> j 7 2
>   7
>   GHCi> j 7 3
>   4
>   GHCi> j 7 11
>   1
>   GHCi> j 77 8
>   1
>   GHCi> j 123 12
>   21

Answer (score 1):

#### Ruby, 39 bytes

```ruby
def J(n,k)
n<2?1:(J(n-1,k)+k-1)%n+1
end
```

Running version with test cases: http://ideone.com/pXOUc

Answer (score 1):

### C, 88 chars

Does the simulation, doesn't calculate the formula.
Much longer than the formula, but shorter than the other C simulation.

```
j(n,k){
    int i=0,c=k,r=n,*p=calloc(n,8);
    for(;p[i=i%n+1]||--c?1:--r?p[i]=c=k:0;);
    return i;
}
```

Notes:
1. Allocates memory and never releases.
2. Allocates `n*8` instead of `n*4`, because I use `p[n]`. Could allocate `(n+1)*4`, but it's more characters.

Answer (score 1):

## Q, 34 bytes

```
f:{$[x=1;1;1+mod[;x]f[x-1;y]+y-1]}
```

Usage:

```
q)f .'(7 1;7 2;7 3;7 11;77 8;123 12)
7 7 4 1 1 21
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 34 bytes

```
J=->n,k{n<2?1:(J(n-1,k)+k-1)%n+1}
```

Answer (score 1):

### C++, 166 bytes

#### Golfed:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include <list>
int j(int n,int k){if(n>1){return(j(n-1,k)+k-1)%n+1;}else{return 1;}}
int main(){intn,k;std::cin>>n>>k;std::cout<<j(n,k);return 0;}
```

#### Ungolfed:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include <list>
int j(int n,int k){
    if (n > 1){
        return (j(n-1,k)+k-1)%n+1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n, k;
    std::cin>>n>>k;
    std::cout<<j(n,k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could save bytes on the `J` function, by using the ternary operator.

Comment: `intn` in your golfed version won't compile

Comment: you can remove space in `#include <list>`

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 56 bytes

```powershell
param($n,$k)if($n-lt2){1}else{((.\f($n-1)$k)+$k-1)%$n+1}
```

Important! The script calls itself recursively. So save the script as `f.ps1` file in the current directory. Also you can call a script block variable instead script file (see the test script below). That calls has same length.

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

param($n,$k)if($n-lt2){1}else{((&$f($n-1)$k)+$k-1)%$n+1}

}

@(
    ,(7, 1, 7)
    ,(7, 2, 7)
    ,(7, 3, 4)
    ,(7, 11, 1)
    ,(77, 8, 1)
    ,(123,12, 21)
) | % {
    $n,$k,$expected = $_
    $result = &$f $n $k
    "$($result-eq$expected): $result"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: 7
True: 7
True: 4
True: 1
True: 1
True: 21
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 6 bytes

```
+~/\,@0%+_@
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWq7Xr9GN0HAxUteMdICJQiTXRSoZGSjpAwlgpFioGAA)

Uses the formula as described on Wikipedia:
\$J(n,k) = g(n,k) + 1\$, where

$$\begin{align}g(1,k) &= 0 \\ g(n,k) &= (g(n-1,k)+k) \bmod n\end{align}$$

```
+~/\,@0%+_@
+~          Add 1
  /          fold right
   \          reverse
    ,          range from 1 to
     @          n
      0       with initial value 0
       %      modulo
        +      add
         _      k
          @     accumutalor
               item
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 29

Using the formula from wikipedia.

```
1#_=1
n#k=mod((n-1)#k+k-1)n+1
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ECMAScript 5), 48 bytes

Using ECMAScript 5 since that was the latest version of JavaScript at the time this question was asked.

```
function f(a,b){return a<2?1:(f(a-1,b)+b-1)%a+1}
```

### ES6 version (non-competing), 33 bytes

```
f=(a,b)=>a<2?1:(f(a-1,b)+b-1)%a+1
```

### Explanation

Not much to say here. I'm just implementing the function the Wikipedia article gives me.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
L[Dg#²<FÀ}¦
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fJ9olXfnQJhu3ww21h5b9/29oZMxlaAQA)

```
L           # Range 1 .. n
 [Dg#       # Until the array has a length of 1:
     ²<F }  #   k - 1 times do:
        À   #     Rotate the array
          ¦ #   remove the first element
```

Answer (score 0):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), 82 bytes

**Code**

```
: j >r >r a:new ( a:push ) 1 r> loop ( r@ n:+ swap n:mod ) 0 a:reduce n:1+ rdrop ;
```

**SED** (Stack Effect Diagram) is: `n k -- m`

**Usage and explanation**

The algorithm uses an array of integers like this: if people value is 5 then the array will be [1,2,3,4,5]

```
: j \ n k -- m
    >r                               \ save k
    >r a:new ( a:push ) 1 r> loop    \ make array[1:n]
    ( r@ n:+ swap n:mod ) 0 a:reduce \ translation of recursive formula with folding using an array with values ranging from 1 to n
    n:1+                             \ increment to move from 0-based to 1-based indexing
    rdrop                            \ clean r-stack
;

ok> 7 1 j . cr
7
ok> 7 2 j . cr
7
ok> 7 3 j . cr
4
ok> 7 11 j . cr
1
ok> 77 8 j . cr
1
ok> 123 12 j . cr
21
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 24 bytes

```
1+1{1([:|/\+)/@,.1|.!.0#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcexCoAgFEbh3af4q6Gk0K4OhiH0HgkNkURLQ2P17HYbPjjnyOlC8OjBMrV0UzP7R8dW6qlT9KhC9VWWolSoU/A1Orwe6RJiW/cTi0EzJi0jHIgZZv/mcRhAxrL8AQ)

An iterative approach based on the dynamic programming solution.

### Explanation

```
1+1{1([:|/\+)/@,.1|.!.0#  Input: n (LHS), k (RHS)
                       #  Make n copies of k
                 1|.!.0   Shift left by 1 and fill with zero
    1          ,.         Interleave with 1
             /@           Reduce using
           +                Addition
        |/\                 Cumulative reduce using modulo
  1{                      Select value at index 1
1+                        Add 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 19 bytes

```
1+(}:@|.^:({:@])i.)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DbU1aq0cavTirDSqrRxiNTP1NP9rcqUmZ@QrGCqkKZhDmEYIpjGCaYikwgLEhImDlBsaGf8HAA)

#### How it works

```
1+(}:@|.^:({:@])i.)   Left: k, Right: n
                i.    Generate [0..n-1]
        ^:            Repeat:
   }:@|.                Rotate left k items, and remove the last item
          ({:@])        n-1 (tail of [0..n-1]) times
1+                    Add one to make the result one-based
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), 33 bytes

```
f(n,k)=>n<2?1:(f(n-1,k)+k-1)%n+1;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc1BCsIwEAXQfU8xi0oTOhUnFSrW1pWnCFkEpbQUo4TETcnZYxC0bj7/DQP/pq2LcWAGZ9715iTOdGSJFaVDOVfEN6akNt71ZBhfMoCXtuCgA5k6gGyQsFH4hfhHjfsVQIT0Y4OHVSRqJIGCVLJqs5RuOzzsRV9HxvxnFuBpJ@NYkS8D83Kn0EtSPEDXQ754KVQoeJseQ8oQ3w)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 15 bytes

```
_é1-V Å}h[Uõ] Ì
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=X+kxLVYgxX1oW1X1XSDM&input=MTIzCjEy)

A byte could be saved by [0-indexing k](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=X+lWbinFfWhbVfVdIMw=&input=MTIzCjEx), but it isn't actually an index so I decided against that.

Explanation:

```
         [Uõ]      :Starting with the array [1...n]
_      }h          :Repeat n-1 times:
 é1-V              : Rotate the array right 1-k times (i.e. rotate left k-1 times)
      Å            : Remove the new first element
              Ì    :Get the last value remaining
```

Answer (score 0):

## Japt `-h`, 10 bytes

```
õ
£=éVn1¹v
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=9QqjPelWbjG5dg==&input=NzcsOAotaA==)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>11</s></sup> 8 bytes

```
Ωεȯtṙ←⁰ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zKc1tPrC95uHPmo7YJjxo3PNyx@P///4ZGQGQMAA)

Algorithm from [Kamil Drakari's answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177098/80214)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 17 bytes

```apl
{¯1↓⍺⌽⍵}⍣{1=≢⍺}∘⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/rQesNHbZMf9e561LP3Ue/W2ke9i6sNbR91LgIK1T7qmPGod/P/tEdtEx719j3qan7Uu@ZR75ZD640ftU181Dc1OMgZSIZ4eAb/N1RIUzDnMgKTxmDSECJkASKBPJCUoZExAA)

Takes input as `k  f  n`.

### Explanation

```apl
{¯1↓⍺⌽⍵}⍣{2=≢⍵}∘⍳
               ∘⍳ list from 1..n
        ⍣         (f⍣g) → apply f repeatedly till g is true
{¯1↓⍺⌽⍵}          f: rotate list through k elements, drop last
         {1=≢⍺}   g: is the length = 1, for the previous iteration?
```

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 36 bytes

```apl
1+{⍺>1:⍺|⍵+⍵∇⍨⍺-1⋄0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///31C7@lHvLjtDKyBZ86h3qzYQP@pof9S7Aiiga/iou8Wg9n/ao7YJj3r7HnU1P@pd86h3y6H1xo/aJj7qmxoc5AwkQzw8g/8bKqQBNSmYcxnBGMYwhiFczgLKAIpBlRkaGQMA)

Recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
RṙṖ¥ƬṖṪ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o4c6ZD3dOO7T02Bog9XDnqv@Hlyv9/x9trqOAQEBsaGQc@z/aUEfBSEfBGMgFsixAorEA)

### How it works

```
RṙṖ¥ƬṖṪ - Main link. Takes n on the left and k on the right
R       - Range; Yield [1, 2, ..., n]
   ¥Ƭ   - Do the following to a fixed point and collect intermediate steps:
 ṙ      -   Rotate k steps to the left
  Ṗ     -   Remove the last element
     Ṗ  - Remove the empty list (the fixed point)
      Ṫ - Return the single element left over
```