# Ninja Assassins - which ninja stays alive?

Tags: code-golf

### Ninja Assassins - which ninja stays alive

**some basic information**

- given an int N as the number of ninjas, return the number of the winning ninja.
- At the end only 1 ninja survives,the question is which one? what was his number?.
- Each ninja kills the ninja who stands after him. Afterwards, he passes the sword to the first alive ninja who stood after the killed one.

### **Explenation - How the Game Works**

The ninjas are numbered from 1 to N and stand in a circle according to the numbers. The circle goes clockwise: ninja 2 is left to ninja 1, ninja 3 is left to ninja 2, ninja 4 is left to ninja 3.... ninja 1 is left to ninja N. 

Ninja 1 gets a sword and the game begins:

Each ninja (starting from ninja 1) kills the closest and alive ninja he has to the left (clockwise) . Afterwards, he passes the sword to the 2nd closest and alive ninja he has to the left.The 2nd ninja does the same (kills and passes) (as an example: N=3(we have 3 ninjas), ninja 1 kills ninja 2 and gives the sword to ninja 3. Ninja 3 has ninja 1 as his closest and alive ninja to the left(clockwise - its a circle) so he kills ninja 1, stays the last ninja alive and wins (so the output\return is 3, as the number of the ninja)). 

**A more detailed example below**

### Example - Word-detailed scenario

**N = 7 (we got 7 ninjas) :**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 (L=alive, D=dead)
L D L L L L L The first ninja gets the sword and kills the 2nd ninja.
              The first ninja passes the sword to the 3rd ninja.
L D L D L L L The 3rd ninja gets the sword and kills the 4th ninja.
              The 3rd Ninja passes the sword to the 5th ninja.
L D L D L D L The 5th ninja gets the sword and kills the 6th ninja.
              The 5th Ninja passes the sword to the 7th ninja.
D D L D L D L The 7th ninja gets the sword and kills the first(1st) ninja.
              The 7th ninja passes the sword to the 3rd ninja.
D D L D D D L The 3rd ninja gets the sword and kills the 5th ninja.
              The 3rd ninja passes the sword to the 7th ninja.
D D D D D D L The 7th ninja gets the sword and kills the 3rd ninja,
              stays as the last one alive and wins (the final result /
              the output is 7).
```

### More scenarios without words

**N=3 :** 1 2 3 - 1 3 - 3 wins 
**N=4 :** 1 2 3 4 - 1 3 - 1 wins
**N=5 :** 1 2 3 4 5 - 1 3 5 - 3 5 - 3 wins 
**N=6 :** 1 2 3 4 5 6 - 1 3 5 - 1 5 - 5 wins 
**N=7 :** 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 - 1 3 5 7 - 3 7 - 7 wins

**Scoring is based on the least number of bytes used, as this is a code-golf question.**

Comment: can it be 0-indexed, i.e. ninja 1 becomes ninja 0, etc.?

Comment: This is the [Josephus Problem](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5891/14215) with constant k=2.

Comment: [Obligatory OEIS A006257](https://oeis.org/A006257).

Comment: The tags code golf, code challenge, and fastest code are mutually exclusive. You can only have one win criterion. I'd suggest code golf.

Answer (score 8):

### Python 2, 30 bytes

```python
lambda n:int(bin(n)[3:]+'1',2)
```

Takes the binary expansion of `n` and moves the initial `1` to the end.

Comment: That is witchcraft.

Comment: **ಠ_ಠ what is this**

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2, 32 bytes

```python
a=lambda n:n and(n%2+a(n/2))*2-1
```

---

**33 bytes:**

```python
a=lambda n:n and 2*a(n/2)-(-1)**n
```

Uses the recursive formula on the [OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A006257).

- `a(2*n) = 2*a(n)-1`
- `a(2*n+1) = 2*a(n)+1`

Comment: Why `a=`? Do you need it?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere To recurse.

Answer (score 2):

### Java 7, <s>65</s> 53 bytes

```
int f(int n){return(n-Integer.highestOneBit(n))*2+1;}
```

Using the algorithm for k=2 Josephus from Wikipedia. Thanks to Leaky Nun for finding the builtin.

Comment: `i&i-1` saves 2 bytes

Comment: Spare parens ftw >_>

Comment: `int f(int n){return(n-Integer.highestOneBit(n))*2+1;}`

Comment: Dammit, I was doing `highestOneBit` manually and got it to 56 just now. I didn't know there was a built-in for it :/

Comment: Yeah, I use Java 7 for golfing just to avoid shady (imo) lambda nonsense :P

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>22</s> <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 9 bytes

Credits to [Geobit's algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83820/48934) for saving 9 bytes. It works like magic.

Credits to [xnor's witchcraft](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83824/48934) for saving 3 bytes. It is simply witchcraft.

```
heu+G=Z%e.f!/G%ZQ2ZQQY
u?sIlH1+2GSQ1
hyaefgQT^L2
i.<.BQ1 2
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=i.%3C.BQ1+2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## Jelly, 4 bytes

Since xnor came up with [this algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83824/48934), I will make this community wiki.

```
Bṙ1Ḅ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=QuG5mTHhuIQ&input=&args=Ng)

### Explanation

```
Bṙ1Ḅ
B     convert to binary
 ṙ1   left-rotate by 1
   Ḅ  convert from binary
```

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, <strike>57</strike> 67 bytes

Well, this technically ought to work (57 bytes):

```
Function Z(N):Z=2*(N-2^Int(Log(N)/Log(2)))+1:End Function
```

But actually, because occasionally the log value of a power of two is not quite an exact multiple of the log of 2, we need a few more bytes:

```
Function Z(N):Z=2*(N-2^Int(Log(N)/Log(2))):Z=1-Z*(Z<N):End Function
```

If there were a built-in binary converter, it would be much shorter.

The recursion version is a tie, basically, but needs a line-feed for the IF

```
Function Y(N):Y=1:If N>1 Then Y=2*Y(N\2)+2*(N\2=N/2)+1
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

## J, 10 bytes

```
(1&|.)&.#:
```

Using the formula where *a*(*n*) = *n* written in binary and rotated left by 1 place. Similar to what is used in @xnor's [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83824/6710).

Using **19 bytes**, we can play the game according to the rules in the challenge.

```
[:(2&}.,{.)^:_>:@i.
```

This solution only performs array manipulation in order to reach a final player.

### Usage

Extra commands used for formatting multiple input/output with multiple functions.

```
   f =: (1&|.)&.#:
   g =: [:(2&}.,{.)^:_>:@i.
   (,.f"0,.g"0) i. 10
0 0 0
1 1 1
2 1 1
3 3 3
4 1 1
5 3 3
6 5 5
7 7 7
8 1 1
9 3 3
```

### Explanation

```
(1&|.)&.#:  Input: n
        #:  Convert to binary
(    )&.    Compose next function on the binary value
 1&|.       Rotate left by 1 place
(    )&.    Compose the inverse of the previous function on the result
        #:  The inverse: convert from binary to decimal and return result

[:(2&}.,{.)^:_>:@i.  Input: n
                 i.  Creates the range [0, 1, ..., n-1]
              >:@    Increment each in the range to get [1, 2, ..., n]
[:(       )^:_       Nest the function until the result does not change and return
   2&}.              Drop the first two items in the list
        {.           Get the head of the list
       ,             Join them together. This makes it so that the head of the list
                     is always the current player and the one after the head is the
                     player to be removed
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 29 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n&n-1<1or f(n-1)+2
```

Outputs 1 as `True` when `n` is a power of 2, checked by `n&n-1` being 0. Otherwise, outputs `2` higher than the previous value.

---

**28 bytes:**

Adapting [grc's general solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5895/20260) to the case `k=2` gives a better solution

```python
f=lambda n:n and-~f(n-1)%n+1
```

Rather than explicitly checking for powers of `2`, it zeroes out the result before incrementing each time `f(n-1)` catches up to `n-1`